# Line 32, Column 9 1119: Access of possibly undefined property Severity through a reference with static type SDCClassN

Tags: actionscript-3, c++-cli, adobe

I use Adobe Animate CC 2017 to migrate AS2.0 to AS 3.0
the compiler gives below error when I publish the .fla file.
"Line 32, Column 9           1119: Access of possibly undefined property Severity through a reference with static type SDCClassN."

below is my code:
I get below error:
C:\delete_it\Adobe_animate_testing\Animate_Practice\SDCClassN.as, Line 32, Column 9           1119: Access of possibly undefined property Severity through a reference with static type SDCClassN.

### Below is the description of my fla file

I have a symbol [Movie clip] in the .fla which changes its color and text when it receives input from the C++ program

### Below is the source code sample we use to send information to the movie clip

```
AxShockwaveFlashObjects::AxShockwaveFlash^ axShockwaveFlash;
axShockwaveFlash->SetVariable(strID + ".ID.text", strID);
axShockwaveFlash->SetVariable(strID + ".mSeverity", "0");
axShockwaveFlash->SetVariable(strID + ".Status.text", String::Empty);
```

---

*****************AS 3.0 code *****************

```
 package  { 
        import flash.display.MovieClip; 
        import flash.text.TextField;          
        public class SDCClassN extends MovieClip
         {                           
             public var mID:String = "SDC"; 
             public var mStatus:String = "NO Com."; 
             public var mSeverity:Number = 2;                             
             public function SDCClassN() { 
              // constructor code 
              this.setID(this.mID); 
              this.setStatus(this.mStatus); 
              this.setSeverity(this.mSeverity); 
                        }                               
              public function setStatus(Variable:String): void{ 
                    this.mStatus = Variable; 
                    this.Status.text = this.mStatus; 
                    this.Status.visible = false; 
                        };                              
              public function setID(Variable:String): void { 
                    this.mID = Variable; 
                    this.ID.text = this.mID; 
                        }; 

              public function setSeverity(Variable:Number):void { 
                    this.mSeverity = Variable; 
                    this.Severity.text = this.mSeverity; 
                        };               
              }               
        }
```

“SDCClassN” class is associated with my movie clip “SDC” and  I have added three properties to the movie clip 
I am not sure if Its correct way to do it the compiler does not like above action script code and throw below error 
C:\delete_it\Adobe_animate_testing\Animate_Practice\SDCClassN.as, Line 32, Column 9           1119: Access of possibly undefined property Severity through a reference with static type SDCClassN. 
Please give me some idea so that I can overcome on this. Please let me know if you need some more details, I can share my .fla file with you.
Please help !!!

Comment: I don't think you can set random root variables the old way. In AS3 you communicate with container via **ExternalInterface** class: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html

Comment: Looks like you are gettingtrough to the setSeverity() but your Severity reference is null. How do you add this Severity to your SDCClassN MovieClip? Probably you add it after your setSeverity is called. Even if you do it before it takes a while once it is available as a reference in your class. A safe way is to listen for the Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE on your Severity and once it is added to the stage then call the setSeverity()